# SQL - Fill column value base on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a sql table look like this

[image]

I would like to update Message column with Alpha if it's ID 1058 and 2045 with Bravo and 3899 with Charlie.

The ID and Message will be different all the time when we import the flat file. It will not always be 1058 2045 3899 and alpha charlie bravo.

Thanks!

Comment: So you'll receive x number of rows and you want to put x1 = alpha, x2 = bravo, x3 = charlie, x4 = delta etc? Can you show us what you've tried before? Also, can you replace the image with the actual table data? That way we can help more quickly.

Comment: @deilgemini . . . Your table already has that information, so an `update` doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET Message = (SELECT t2.Message FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Message IS NOT NULL)
WHERE
    Message IS NULL;
```

This update will target all records having a `NULL` (missing) message, and will replace that message with the non `NULL` value from a record having the same `ID`.  Note that we could also write this logic using an update join, but the exact syntax would depend on your particular database, which you did not mention.

For SQL Server, here is one way to do this using update join logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.Message AS msgTarget, t2.Message AS msgSource
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    WHERE t1.Message IS NULL AND t2.Message IS NOT NULL
)

UPDATE cte
SET msgTarget = msgSource;
```

Comment: @devil My first answer should work on pretty much any database.  I have included a version specifically for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need at lest one condition to update data in database.
If old data is not required you can delete all and insert new records.

if this doesn't solve your problem, may be some database structure level changes required.

Answer (score -1):

U need to do a conditional update with a join. Depends on the engine but an example would be like below

```
UPDATE  A
Set A.Message=B.Message
From Table A
INNER JOIN  
(Select distinct id, message from table) B
ON A.id=B.id
Where A.Message is null
```

Comment: How do you know which RDBMS the OP is using?